# How to receive/handle an XMPP message send to a user running Spring Boot / Integration

Tags: spring, xmpp, spring-boot, spring-integration, smack

Currently i have a runnning Spring Boot application that logs in into a XMPP server as a specific user. I can send messages to remote clients etc. But now i want to receive messages on the serverside if clients are sending messages to that specific user that is logged in via Spring Boot.

I tried to hookup a service activator that actually receives a message but the message content is put into the "to" field and the "from" property is null. So i am puzzled on how to hook up things..

Below is the xmpp configuration of the incoming message adapter:

```
<!-- incoming xmpp configuration -->
<int-xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter auto-startup="true" xmpp-connection="xmppConnection" channel="incomingMessagesChannel"/>
<channel id="incomingMessagesChannel">
    <interceptors>
        <wire-tap channel="incomingMessagesLogger"/>
    </interceptors>
</channel>
<logging-channel-adapter id="incomingMessagesLogger" logger-name="incoming logger" log-full-message="true" />
<service-activator ref="messageEventHandler" method="handle" input-channel="incomingMessagesChannel"/>
```

And the class that handles the incoming messages:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MessageEventHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageEventHandler.class);

    public void handle(Message message) {
        System.out.println(message.getFrom());
        System.out.println(message.getTo());
        System.out.println(message.getBody());
    }
}
```

So when i send a message to the server the output of:

- `System.out.println(message.getFrom());` is `null`
- `System.out.println(message.getTo());` is the actual message content
- `System.out.println(message.getBody());` is `null`

What am i missing overhere?

Comment: Which Spring Integration version do you use? Try with the latest `4.1.3`. We upgraded `4.0` to the `Smack 4.0`. I've just tested it with Gmail and works well. Or you external client is bad, or the old `Smack 3.2` in Spring Integration 3.0 is really invalid...

Comment: It seems that the inbound channel needs a extract-payload="false" then it all seems to work ok! I was under the impression that this would be the default.

Comment: No reason to make it `false` by default, because all those `to`, `from` and other XMPP properties are mapped to the `MessageHeaders`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Could you please explain what the correct setting would be? If i do not set it to default `false` then the data is incorrectly mapped.

Comment: if you make it as default (`extractPayload`) you should handle just `String` as a `payload` or he whole `org.springframework.messaging.Message`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan you are right i was using the wrong message implementation and not using the Spring Message interface. Thanks for pointing me out!

Answer (score 2):

Solution to this problem was to use the correct Message implementation!

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MessageEventHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageEventHandler.class);

    public void handle(Message message) {
        MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();

        String from = (String) headers.get("xmpp_from");
        String to = (String) headers.get("xmpp_to");
        Long timestamp = (Long) headers.get("timestamp");
        String payload = (String) message.getPayload();

        logger.debug("Received a message from: {} with payload: {}", from, payload);
    }
}
```